# Remap the . in the numpad?

Tags: keyboard

In my locale digits are represented like this: 100,90 (instead of 100.90 as in the USA), but, even using a PC keyboard, OS X 10.7 is replacing the `.` in the numpad with a  `,` via software

This is ***REALLY*** annoying, for example:

- I type IP address: 192,168,1,1
- I type terminal commands: ,/myscript.sh and so on

How I could swap the `,` for a `.` but only on the numpad?

Comment: You really need to let us know what you are actually using for us to help.  Any additional hardware/OS level information would be most usful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/37042/remapping-of-keys-in-mac-os-x) on superuser discusses a similar problem. The accepted answer points to [this key mapping program](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) which you may find meets your needs.

The other, more robust but slightly more complex solution, would be to create your own custom keyboard layout using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). You can then install your custom layout in your  ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts folder, and activate it using the System Preferences -> International pane. (the best way to use Ukelele is to duplicate your existing Turkish keyboard layout file and modify just the single key in question).

As a fast solution, and if you don't mind changing other keys on the keyboard, you could use the International pane to switch to a US keyboard layout.

Comment: Love it! Found my **exact** case in the keyremap4macbook! It means I am not the only one with this weird mapping problem - Apple should listen to users...